# AstroNvim does not recognize Python modules installed in a virtual environment

Tags: python, neovim, pyright

I am using the AstroNvim configuration with pyright and pylint installed via Mason. Neovim doesn't recognize the imported modules installed via pip in a virtual environment, but it executes just fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jprDm.png)

I tried using pyrightconfig.json but it still doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNo7m.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you enter virtual env before opening nvim? What is the virtual env environment variable value insude neovim? What 'executes just fine' exactly? What do you execute and how, what do you type and what is the result?